# An Idea for Debug Output

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have written a simple ExpressionEngine add-on that I think may help us better help people asking for help here.

Something I've noticed when trying to answer questions is that people often don't tell us information that could really help us diagnose their problem in a matter of minutes.

My add-on produces markdown that a user copies and pastes into a site like Github Gists and links into their question. For example:- https://gist.github.com/andrewfairlie/48960b15d404b1f00cea

In the instance that a user only wants us to see their installation data they would run `{exp:rc_debug include="installation"}` and it would output https://gist.github.com/andrewfairlie/27c0bf52418b8cfff96c

An example of where this could be handy is when diagnosing an add-on that uses a hook. By checking `{exp:rc_debug include="extensions"}` we could see without asking for control panel access if another extension is using the same hook at a conflicting permission.

Or with the new EE 2.8 template routes we might see an influx of those questions, we could ask people to provide us with `{exp:rc_debug include="templates|template_routes"}` so we can see what's wrong with them.

Available from: https://github.com/andrewfairlie/rc_debug

Comment: This is really awesome Andrew :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice job Andrew, I can see this being really useful. My only concern would be that we should ask people to be judicious in using the full array of options, as I could see it leading to many questions which have many page lengths of content pasted in unnecessarily so.

But yes, I think it's a great idea for people to start linking to your add-on when answering questions which merit it.

Comment: I agree Derek. If people just throw everything in the include it becomes increasingly less useful.